# Insert SQL code into database in PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, escaping

I'm trying to write sql to insert a SQL code into one of the table's columns.
The table has these three columns: email, verification code, sql.

I try this code, and variations of it, playing around with the quotes and backslashing/escaping them, etc... but something's still wrong:

```
INSERT INTO pre_registration(email, verification_code, sql) VALUES('myemail@gmail.com', '8efb100a295c0c690931222ff4467bb8', '"INSERT INTO customer(title) VALUES(\'Mr.\')"')
```

It tells me there's an error in the SQL syntax:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql) VALUES('myemail@gmail.com', '89f0fd5c927d466d6ec9a21b9ac34ffa', "INSER' at line 1
```

How to do it? I'm using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: What exact error does it report? And on what RDBMS?  It actually looks like it would work correctly for most...

Comment: I've edited the question to include the error. I'm using php/MySQL.

Comment: `SQL` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) You must quote it in backticks to use as a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some insight into the exact SQL error would help. At first glance I'd say you need to apply spaces between the table name and the open parentheses and between values and the open parentheses.

Also, the Single quotes around the double quotes for the SQL portion may be creating an error though I am not certain. Whatever is between the single quotes is interpreted literally which should make the escape characters actually be slashes inside the stored data.

Also, sql is a reserved word that must be quoted for use.

Finally, depending on your situation there may be a more secure method of data entry using prepare and bound parameters:

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO ( "sqlsrv:server = $serverstringname; Database = $logindatabase", "$loginusername", "$loginpassword");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch ( PDOException $e )
{
    print( "Error connecting to SQL Server." );
    die(print_r($e));
}

$email = 'myemail@gmail.com' //or some other way of setting the variable like $_POST
$verification_code = '#####' //or $_Post method
$sql = 'Put Query Here' //probably have to declare this explicitly

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO pre_registration_info (email, verification_code, 'sql') VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_insert);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $email);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $verification_code);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $sql);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `'sql'` should be surrounded by backtick not quote.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL considers `sql` as a keyword. You have to quote it:

```
INSERT INTO pre_registration(email, verification_code, `sql`) VALUES('myemail@gmail.com', '8efb100a295c0c690931222ff4467bb8', '"INSERT INTO customer(title) VALUES(\'Mr.\')"')
```

By the way double the quotes to escape them instead of using bakslashes. This is more SQL friendly.

```
INSERT INTO pre_registration(email, verification_code, `sql`) VALUES('myemail@gmail.com', '8efb100a295c0c690931222ff4467bb8', '"INSERT INTO customer(title) VALUES(''Mr.'')"')
```

Comment: In MySQL quotes can be backslash-escaped

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski OK, I have retagge the question.